# How to update field with value from other table with several joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables, all of them with an auto-incremental ID:

- `customer`
- `customer_category`: Each customer has a category
- `delivery_note`: Each note has a customer and a set of entries
- `delivery_note_entry`: an entry belongs to a note, and has a product, a quantity, and a base_price, copied from product.
- `product`: Product to purchase. Its price depends on the customer category
- `product_price`: sets the price of a product for a given `customer_category`.

So my problem is some prices have been updated, but there was a typo in some of them and now I need to set the prices in some delivery notes. I can list what I want to do using:

```
select dn.id as "note ID",
  dne.id as "entry",
  dne.product_id "product ID",
  dne.base_price as "current price",
  pp.price as "to be price"
from product_price pp
join delivery_note_entry dne on dne.product_id = pp.product_id 
join delivery_note dn on dn.id=dne.delivery_note_id 
join customer c on dn.customer_id = c.id
join customer_category cc on cc.id = c.customer_category_id 
where dn.creation_date between '2020-08-28' and '2020-08-29'
```

But I am not able to build the update query to change prices. I've tried

```
update delivery_note_entry dne set base_price = pp.price 
from product_price pp
join delivery_note dn on dn.id = delivery_note_id 
join customer c on dn.customer_id = c.id
join customer_category cc on cc.id = c.customer_category_id_2 
where dne.product_id = pp.product_id 
and dn.creation_date between '2020-08-28' and '2020-08-29'
```

But I get the following error using DBeaver:

> ```
> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "delivery_note_id" does not exist
>   Hint: There is a column named "delivery_note_id" in table "dne",
> but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, most of the conditions are for filtering.  Hence, I think this does what you want:

```
update delivery_note_entry dne
    set base_price = (select pp.price from product_price pp where dne.product_id = pp.product_id)
from delivery_note dn join
     customer c
     on dn.customer_id = c.id join
     customer_category cc
     on cc.id = c.customer_category_id 
where dn.id = dne.delivery_note_id and
      dn.creation_date between '2020-08-28' and '2020-08-29';
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you don't need a subquery:

```
update delivery_note_entry dne
    set base_price = pp.price
from delivery_note dn join
     customer c
     on dn.customer_id = c.id join
     customer_category cc
     on cc.id = c.customer_category_id join
     product_price pp
     on pp.customer_category_id = c.customer_category_id
where dn.id = dne.delivery_note_id and
      dne.product_id = pp.product_id and
      dn.creation_date between '2020-08-28' and '2020-08-29';
```

Comment: I need to change some things to test it (the scenario in the question has been somewhat simplified) so I'm still checking it. I think I can remove the join with customer_category in the same way I "shortcut" the `product`table.

Comment: It gave me an error (multiple results in the select clause), but then I modified the select clause adding a condition with `select pp.price from product_price pp where dne.product_id = pp.product_id and pp.customer_category_id =c.customer_category_id`

Comment: @PabloLozano . . . That makes sense.  That condition is not in the question.  But with that change, it now makes sense to eliminate the subquery and move the table into the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

can you pls try -

```
UPDATE delivery_note_entry dne 
set  dne.base_price =(
select pp.price 
from product_price pp
join delivery_note dn on dn.id=dne.delivery_note_id 
join customer c on dn.customer_id = c.id
join customer_category cc on cc.id = c.customer_category_id 
where 
dn.creation_date between '2020-08-28' and '2020-08-29'
)
where dne.product_id = pp.product_id and
```

Comment: I think this will update ALL the delivery_note_entry entries, which I don't want to. I think the where clause should be outside

Comment: i doubt but still changed.